# Sorting query results

Tags: sql, sorting

How can I properly sort the results to show the results in the following order

```
1st - Parent Name   
2nd - Child Name  
3rd - Teacher Name  
4th - Other Name
```

Where the parent name and child name is on the same table Family

```
id | parent name | child name
-----------------------------  
1    Denz          Hanz  
2    Denz          Pog  
3    Joann         Mac
```

while the other names are on different tables teacher table

```
id | teacher name  
-----------------  
1     Miguel  
2     Sean
```

and Other_guest table

```
id | guest name
-----------------
1   Mike  
2   Mal
```

where in cases that the parent did not arrive, the child name will be showed. Result of the query should show something like this

```
Participant Name
----------------
1. Denz 
2. Denz  
3. Mac 
4. Miguel 
5. Sean  
6. Mal 
7. Mike
```

I tried using order by field(),order by field asc, field2 dec ... etc but it seems not the result we wanted.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (you didn't even bother to label with general SQL)?

Comment: what's your database structure? can you show us some queries you have tried?

Comment: Sorry Tim but first time posting. the sql version is 5.1.73-log for linux.

Comment: that's not the SQL database you are using, just its version. While some people can deduce which one it is, you will get better responses if you use the whole name, like `mySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `SQL Server`, `Oracle` etc.

Comment: I tried to simplify the actual problem description above but the problem is still the same.

Comment: its mysql  and this is the actual sql statement i am working on `SELECT
c.subject Service,
count(DISTINCT c.transaction_id) Count,
sum(IF(y.payModeName='Cash',y.amount,0)) As Cash,
sum(If(s.name=c.subject,0,c.amount)) As TotalCharges,
sum(c.tax)*count(DISTINCT c.transaction_id)/count(*) Tax,
sum(y.amount) As TotalPayments
FROM Transaction t
LEFT JOIN Charge c ON t.id=c.transaction_id
LEFT JOIN Payment y ON t.id=y.transaction_id
LEFT JOIN SubsidyPlan s ON c.subject=s.name
WHERE 1=1
AND t.clinic_id = 19
GROUP BY Service
ORDER BY Service `

Comment: definitely drop the 1=1 condition, it does nothing :) also, please tell us more how this query is related to data you have included in your question? because I'm confused about who parent/children etc. are here.

Answer (score 0):

Below query works in most of the databases, this query will first sort by type and then name:

```
select * from (
select parent_name, 0 sort_by from table1
union all
select chile_name, 1 from table1
union all
select teacher_name, 2 from table2
union all
select guest_name, 3 from table3) t
order by sort_by, parent_name;
```

Comment: Thanks Durga, I'll try this template.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for Oracle DB:

Note that the UNION does not allow ORDER BY clause in subsequent select statements, therefore a procedure is necessary that generates the list of guests in the GUESTS table.

The table ARRIVED contains the IDs of the arrived parents, all other tables are self explanatory.

```
create table Family (id number, parentname varchar2(100), childname varchar2(100));
create table Teacher (id number, teachername varchar2(100));
create table Other_guest (id number, guestname varchar2(100));
create table Arrived (id number);
create table Guests (guestname varchar2(100));

create sequence Family_seq start with 1 order;
create sequence Teacher_seq start with 1 order;
create sequence Other_seq start with 1 order;

create or replace trigger Family_id before insert on Family for each row
begin
  select Family_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;

create or replace trigger Teacher_id before insert on Teacher for each row
begin
  select Teacher_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;

create or replace trigger Other_id before insert on Other_guest for each row
begin
  select Other_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;

insert into Family (parentname, childname) values ('Denz', 'Hanz');
insert into Family (parentname, childname) values ('Denz', 'Pog');
insert into Family (parentname, childname) values ('Joann', 'Mac');

insert into Teacher (teachername) values ('Miguel');
insert into Teacher (teachername) values ('Sean');

insert into Other_guest (guestname) values ('Mike');
insert into Other_guest (guestname) values ('Mal');

insert into Arrived (id) values (1);
insert into Arrived (id) values (2);

create or replace procedure update_guest_list as
pragma autonomous_transaction;
cursor c_parents is select parentname from family where id in (select id from arrived) order by family.parentname;
cursor c_children is select childname from family where id not in (select id from arrived) order by family.childname;
cursor c_teachers is select teachername from teacher order by teacher.teachername asc;
cursor c_others is select guestname from other_guest order by other_guest.guestname asc;
begin
  delete from guests;
  for parents_rec in c_parents
  loop
    insert into guests (guestname) values (parents_rec.parentname);
  end loop;
  for children_rec in c_children
  loop
    insert into guests (guestname) values (children_rec.childname);
  end loop;
  for teachers_rec in c_teachers
  loop
    insert into guests (guestname) values (teachers_rec.teachername);
  end loop;
  for others_rec in c_others
  loop
    insert into guests (guestname) values (others_rec.guestname);
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/

execute update_guest_list;
```